# How to use select WHERE clause in jdbcTemplateObject?

Tags: jdbctemplate

I need to use query like this:

```
"select * from Team_has_users where Teams_id_team = ?";
```

If I call this method:

```
    public Team_has_users listTeamMembers(int id_team) {
    String SQL = "select * from Team_has_users where Teams_id_team = ?";
    Team_has_users members = jdbcTemplateObject.queryForObject(SQL, new Object[] { id_team },
            new Team_has_usersMapper());
    return members;
}
```

I get exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 2
```

I have more then one object in DB with the same id_team, so I understand, why it is throwing an excepction, but I need some solution to get all the record from DB.

I thought about using it in method like this, but I don't know how to use it with parameter "id_team".

```
    public List<Team_has_users> listTeamMembers(int id_team) {
    String SQL = "select * from Team_has_users where Teams_id_team = ?";
    List<Team_has_users> members = jdbcTemplateObject.query(SQL, new Team_has_usersMapper());
    return members;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, you have to use `query`. Just pass the argument to the function :

```
List<Team_has_users> members =  getJdbcTemplate().query(SQL, new Team_has_usersMapper(), id_team);
```

By the way, you can check the [jdbcTemplate javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper,%20java.lang.Object...%29).